# zero division error in python code while calculating arithmetic mean

Tags: python, math

```
a=True
k=0 #amount of numbers
s=0 #sum of numbers
print("Enter multiple numerical values. Entering will be completed when you enter 0")
while a==True:
    c=int(input())
    if c>0 or c<0:
        continue
    elif c==0:
        break
    if c!=0:
        s=s+c
        k=k+1
    else:
        a=False
print(str(s/k))
```

i am learning how to code in python language. i tried to code a program that calculates arithmetic mean but zero division error occur when i try to divide s (which is sum of numbers) by k (which is amount of numbers). however, k does not equal zero.

Comment: if you continue when c isn't 0 and then break when it is, when will k ever get chance to change?

Comment: I think you misunderstand what `continue` does.

Comment: `c>0 or c<0` is equivalent to `c != 0`

Comment: `continue` does not mean "proceed with this loop iteration", it means "abort this loop iteration and start the next iteration".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, your code follows one of two paths:

if `c` equals `0` you `break` out of the loop

and

if `c` does not equal `0` i.e. `(c>0 or c<0)` then you `continue` with the next iteration of the loop.

So, the issue boils down to the code that increments `k` and `s` is never executed and then when you go to `print(s/k)` you end up with an divide by 0 exception.

You will still get an exception here if the first entry is `0` but this will do more like what you want to do:

```py
k=0 #amount of numbers
s=0 #sum of numbers

print("Enter multiple numerical values. Entering will be completed when you enter 0")
while True:
    c = int(input())

    if c == 0:
        break

    s = s + c
    k = k + 1

print(s/k)
```

Comment: This probably the best answer to your issue. I would also add that for your future use of if/else statements the structure is typically ```if>elif>else``` with as many elif as necessary. It is not good code to put an if` after elif if you have not concluded it with an else.